# Create tree diagram

Tags: r, visualization, dendrogram

I have data on a company that I want to visualize by a tree diagram. That means, I have their  brands nested in classes, nested in subgroups, nested in divisions (http://www.bayer.com/en/products-from-a-to-z.aspx#B).

Even though there are quite some threads on stackoverflow how to create dendrograms, I did not find a code snippet that worked with my data (such as e.g. [how to convert a data.frame to tree structure object such as dendrogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343338/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-tree-structure-object-such-as-dendrogram)).

**EDIT**:
If I am right "dendrogram" is in this case not the right term as I don't have/consider any kind of distance measure. Such I am using the more generic term "tree diagram"

```
df <- structure(list(Brand = structure(c(73L, 122L, 131L, 44L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 27L, 52L, 84L, 95L, 101L, 121L, 142L, 17L, 21L, 53L, 
86L, 99L, 112L, 139L, 4L, 97L, 76L, 47L, 113L, 146L, 71L, 109L, 
147L, 148L, 149L, 14L, 80L, 93L, 114L, 3L, 15L, 25L, 26L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 56L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 72L, 90L, 92L, 117L, 28L, 91L, 9L, 16L, 81L, 45L, 
51L, 10L, 130L, 138L, 46L, 74L, 116L, 128L, 137L, 11L, 77L, 82L, 
83L, 94L, 111L, 123L, 124L, 134L, 136L, 141L, 18L, 23L, 48L, 
75L, 79L, 87L, 88L, 100L, 102L, 126L, 129L, 50L, 54L, 115L, 5L, 
22L, 85L, 98L, 118L, 127L, 19L, 38L, 107L, 132L, 58L, 120L, 96L, 
2L, 49L, 55L, 20L, 106L, 135L, 143L, 145L, 1L, 133L, 125L, 108L, 
119L, 12L, 24L, 33L, 78L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 13L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 34L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 70L, 89L, 110L, 144L, 64L, 140L), .Label = c("3.0T Prostate eCoil", 
"A1CNow", "Acclaim Polyol", "Adalat", "Admire", "Advantage", 
"Advantix", "Advocate", "Aleve", "Alka-Seltzer", "Antracol", 
"Apec", "Arcol", "Arize", "Artwalk", "Aspirin", "Aspirin Cardio", 
"Atlantis", "Attribut", "Avanta", "Avelox", "Bariton", "Basta", 
"Bayblend", "Baybond", "Baycoll", "Baycox", "Baycusan", "Baydur", 
"Bayfill", "Bayfit", "Bayflex", "Bayfol", "Baygalÿ/Baymidur", 
"Bayhydrol", "Bayhydur", "Bayhytherm", "Bayleton", "Baymer", 
"Baynat", "Baypreg", "Baypren", "Baytec", "Baytril", "Bepanthenÿ/Bepanthol", 
"Berocca", "Betaferonÿ/ Betaseron", "Betanal", "Breezeÿ2", "Calypso", 
"Canesten", "Catosal", "Cipro", "Confidor", "Contourÿ/Contour Linkÿ/Contour TS", 
"CreKat", "Crelan", "Decis", "Desavin", "Desmocap", "Desmocoll", 
"Desmoderm", "Desmodur", "Desmoflex", "Desmolac", "Desmolith", 
"Desmolux", "Desmomelt", "Desmopan", "Desmophen", "Diane", "Dispercoll", 
"Drontal", "Elevit", "Equip", "Eylea", "Fandango", "Fantasia", 
"Fenikan", "FiberMax", "Flanaxÿ/ÿApronax", "Flint", "Folicur", 
"Gadovist", "Gaucho", "Glucobay", "Hoestar", "Husar", "Hyperlite", 
"Imprafix", "Impranil", "Impraperm", "InVigor", "Input", "Iopamiron", 
"K-Othrine", "Kogenate", "Lamardor", "Levitra", "Liberty", "Magnevist", 
"MaisTer", "Makroblend", "Makrofol", "Makrolon", "Mark V ProVis", 
"Maxforce", "Microlet 2", "Mirena", "Multitec", "Nativo", "Nebido", 
"Nexavar", "Nunhems", "Oberon", "One-A-Day", "Pergut", "Poncho", 
"Possis Angio Jet", "Premise", "Primovist", "Profender", "Proline", 
"Prosaro", "Pulsar", "Puma", "Raxil", "Redoxon", "Rely", "Rennie", 
"Rompun", "Ronstar", "Solaris", "Sphere", "Stellant", "Stratego", 
"Supradyn", "Talcid", "Testogel", "Texin", "Twist", "Ultravist", 
"Vistron CT", "Vulkollan", "XDS", "Xarelto", "Yasmin", "Yasminelle", 
"Yaz"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 29L, 33L, 34L, 39L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 
43L, 43L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 41L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
31L, 37L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 21L, 15L, 19L, 21L, 26L, 36L, 
40L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 
38L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 35L, 35L), .Label = c("Agricultural Seed", 
"Agricultural seed", "Analgesics", "Blood Glucose Monitoring Systems", 
"Coatings, adhesives, specialties", "Companion Animal", "Companion Animal / Food Animal Product", 
"Companion animals", "Dermatologicals", "Diagnostic Imaging", 
"Diagnostic imaging", "Drug product for protection against heart attack", 
"Food Animal Product", "Fungal infections", "Fungicides", "Gastrointestinals", 
"General Medicine", "General Medicine / Mens HealthCare", "General insect control", 
"Hematology/cardiology", "Herbicides", "Injection Systems / Cardiology", 
"Injection Systems / Computer Tomography", "Injection Systems / Magnetic Resonance Tomography", 
"Injections Systems Ultrasound", "Insecticides", "Insecticides/seed treatment", 
"Lancing Devices", "Ophthalmology", "Polycarbonates", "Polyurethanes", 
"Seed treatment", "Specialty Medicine", "Specialty Medicine / Onkology", 
"TPU granules", "Termiticides", "Textile coating", "Thrombectomy", 
"Thromboembolic diseases", "Vector and locust control", "Vegetable seed", 
"Vitamins", "Women's healthcare"), class = "factor"), Subgroup = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Bayer CropScience", "Bayer HealthCare", 
"Bayer MaterialScience"), class = "factor"), Division = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("Animal Health", 
"Bayer HealthCare Pharmaceuticals, Germany", "BioScience", "Coatings, Adhesives, Specialties", 
"Consumer Care", "Crop Protection", "Crop Protection/Environmental Science", 
"Environmental Science", "Medical Care", "Polycarbonates", "Polyurethanes", 
"Thermoplastic Polyurethanes"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Brand", 
"Class", "Subgroup", "Division"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-149L))
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: what did you try and what dint work?

Comment: I did try the script given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343338/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-tree-structure-object-such-as-dendrogram. The example worked, but with my data it didn't work out.

Comment: Maybe a bit more detail than "it didn't work out"?

Comment: The dataframe was empty, which the function generates was empty. I was  wondering if you are aware of any package that supports the visualization by tree diagram based on such data out of the box?

Comment: BTW, I already had a look at: http://gastonsanchez.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/7-ways-to-plot-dendrograms-in-r/

Comment: I think you might have to roll your own solution using `diagram` or something similar. Doing a little dinking around with this while on a telecon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `ape`, and assuming your data is `olddat`:

```
library(ape)
newdata <- as.phylo(x=~Division/Subgroup/Class/Brand,data=olddat)
plot.phylo(x=newdata,show.tip.label=TRUE,show.node.label=TRUE,no.margin=TRUE)
```

You'll need to play with your various plot options, but I think this will get you going in the right direction. I'll see about updating the answer if I can get the plot to look okay.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. I will also have a look how to do it in D3 as I find those tree diagrams more appealing (see e.g. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)