# R: Create a simple diagram based on data in data frame with minimal manual input

Tags: r, data-visualization

I would like to create a simple descriptive tree diagram from a data frame with minimal manual work.

It could look like this:

[image]
But it would need to have sample size in each of the boxes.

I am after the following functionality:

1. Generate the plot based on a data frame (rather than the more manual options shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722689/creating-tree-diagram-for-showing-case-count-using-r))
2. Ability to change the order of branches (e.g. sex/agegroup/status vs. status/sex/agegroup)
3. Add labels to each branch
4. Provide summary statistics for branch (e.g. male\n=200 female\n=300) either counts, or perhaps total length of stay up that that point in the tree.

I found this tread ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024626/create-tree-diagram)) that uses the ape-package that can do phylogenetic tree, which are close to what I am after.

Here is an example using the 'lung' dataset

```
lung$status <- factor(lung$status)
lung$sex <- factor(lung$sex)
lung$ph.ecog <- factor(lung$ph.ecog)
lung$Age[lung$age >60]<- "60+"; lung$Age[lung$age <=60]<- "<60"
lung$Age <- factor(lung$Age)


library(ape)
newdata <- as.phylo(x=~sex/Age/status/ph.ecog,data=lung)
plot.phylo(x=newdata,show.tip.label=TRUE,show.node.label=TRUE,no.margin=TRUE, root.edge=T)
```

This is giving close to what I want (although I am not interested in the final nodes, which are patients). It meets criteria 1 & 2, but not 3 and 4. The help of plot.phylo points towards show.node.label() that might fix requirement 3, but I cannot get this to work. Have not found any example that helps with the 4th functionality requirement.

Comment: Check out [DiagrammeR](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR)

Comment: I don't have access to the book at the moment but code to make similar diagrams is in Murrell's book, "R Graphics": https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RG2e/ . I'm guessing that a `table` or `tapply` call with increasing complexity could populate the nodes with the summary statistics. At the moment there are no data to test that notion with. Such a situation is likely to lead to closure on teh grounds of lack of clarity or not have a MWE. You should make more effort on building an example using R code before posting.